# How to do something only if previous step does not end with error?

Tags: project-reactor

I like to guard a call to save with a check (that also talks to db and therefore need also to be reactive). I tried it like this:

```java
service.verifyThatStuffNotExists(stuff.number())
.then(
    service.save(stuff)
).map( 
    savedStuff -> ResponseEntity.created(...) 
);
```

Where the verification call either returns an error Mono when the conditions fails,
or an empty Mono:

```java
Mono<Void> verifyThatStuffNotExists(String stuffNumber) {
  return repository.exitsByNumber(stuffNumber)
      .flatMap(alreadyThere -> {
          if (alreadyThere) {
              return Mono.error(new StuffAlreadyExistingException("Some message"));
          } else {
              return Mono.empty();
          }
      });
}
```

The syntax looks very nice. but it does not work like expected:
the `save` method is called even when the `verify` method returns an error.
I looks like the `then` operator only coordinate the completion.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `then` method replays both complete and error signals, so your code should function as intended.

I suggest checking a few potential problem areas:

1. Make sure that `repository.exitsByNumber(stuffNumber)` never return `Mono.empty` and always return mono true/false.
2. Make sure that `service.save(stuff)` is "lazy" executed. Try to wrap it with Mono.defer like this: `.then(Mono.defer(() -> service.save(stuff)))`.

You can also get rid of `then` operator like this:

```java
<T> Mono<T> saveIfStuffNotExists(String stuffNumber, Mono<T> saveMono) {
    return repository.exitsByNumber(stuffNumber)
        .flatMap(alreadyThere -> {
            if (alreadyThere) {
                return Mono.error(new StuffAlreadyExistingException("Some message"));
            } else {
                return saveMono;
            }
        });
}
```

p.s. Just a quick note - I am not aware of your specific use case, but I feel it's important to caution you that the approach you're considering may not be atomic. Under heavy usage, it could result in duplicate entries. It may be safer to rely on the unique index of your database.

Comment: The second point seem to be the issue: without the "Mono.defer(()->dosomething()) , the function was evaluated always, as the then() is in the end just a function call which evaluates it's parameters.

Answer (score -1):

You can use onErrorReturn to avoid saving data in case of error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.